# _vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx - All of the sudden getting "Cannot connect to server"

Tags: web-services

We are on multi server farm (1 app server and 2 wfe)

The url works in app server and regular client browser. However, does not work from WFE.

So I am getting errors in InfoPath "An error occured while trying to connect to web service". If I edit the infoPath form and do a preview I dont get the error.

What could have gone wrong all of the sudden? I get cannot connect to server from workflow when I use userprofileservice.asmx.

I looked at the ULS log and it says the same thing cannot connect to server. I think this makes sense if I can't resolve the asmx from the WFE.

What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had to modify host entry which was pointing to old host header. After changing the host entry on each WFE with the correct IP and host header the problem went away.